# number picker can't set up

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment, numberpicker

I have problem with a number picker in Android. It displays only 0 value between two horizontal lines. It looks like my settings which I'm trying to set in the code aren't working.
My xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My DialogFragment code:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        // Create the array of numbers that will populate the numberpicker
            final String[] nums = new String[21];
            for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
               nums[i] = Integer.toString(i*5);
            }



     // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scaledialog, null);

      //set up number picker
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.np);
        np.setMaxValue(20);
        np.setMinValue(5);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
        np.setValue(5);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.scaledialog, null))
                //.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           // ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS !!**

setup should be queue after the dialog was build

so use **Post()** and **Runnable()** to achieve this.

```
    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.np);

    np.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String[] nums = new String[21];
            for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
                nums[i] = Integer.toString(i*5);
            }

            np.setMaxValue(20);
            np.setMinValue(5);
            np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
            np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
            np.setValue(5);
        }
    });
```